# Google webmaster tools and duplicated links

Tags: seo, robots.txt, google-search-console

I have some problems and im confusing now with google webmaster tools

I have example:

```
http://site.com/link/text.html
```

and im using CustomVar on google analytics to track clicks from external site
example

```
http://site.com/link/text.html?promoid=123
```

Now in webmaster tools i have toons of duplicated links

In robots.txt im add

```
Disallow: *?promoid
```

but im not sure if this good idea...

What i should do now, still use robots file and disallow **promoid** or maybe use rel="**canonical**" ?

*Edit: all links with ?promoid=123 is posted on external site not on my...*

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly what canonical URLs are for. It will tell Google that `http://site.com/link/text.html` is the main URL to use for that page and that any other page using that canonical URL is just a minor variation of that page.